# permission denied Installing and configuring mod_wsgi

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to  compile the latest m0d_wsgi file using http://grok.zope.org/documentation/tutorial/installing-and-setting-up-grok-under-mod-wsgi/installing-and-configuring-mod-wsgi. In ubuntu 12.04 I have:

```
$./configure mod_wsgi.c --with-python=f:/python/python.exe
```

I am getting:

./configure mod_wsgi.c --with-python=f:/python/python.exe

```
bash: ./configure: Permission denied
```

here is the directory:

```
drwx------ 2 dan dan  16384 2012-08-22 23:12 .
drwx------ 3 dan dan  16384 2013-01-26 21:25 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 dan dan   3782 2013-01-26 23:25 config.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 dan dan  20428 2013-01-26 23:24 config.status
-rw-r--r-- 1 dan dan  80107 2012-08-22 23:10 configure
rw-r--r-- 1 dan dan   5886 2012-08-22 23:10 configure.ac
-rw-r--r-- 1 dan dan     97 2012-08-22 23:10 .hgignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 dan dan     56 2012-08-22 23:10 .hgtags
-rw-r--r-- 1 dan dan  11358 2012-08-22 23:10 LICENCE
-rw-r--r-- 1 dan dan 484936 2012-08-22 23:10 mod_wsgi.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 dan dan   1195 2012-08-22 23:10 posix-ap1X.mk.in
-rw-r--r-- 1 dan dan   1247 2012-08-22 23:10 posix-ap2X.mk.in
-rw-r--r-- 1 dan dan  18063 2012-08-22 23:12 README
-rw-r--r-- 1 dan dan    907 2012-08-22 23:10 win32-ap22py26.mk
-rw-r--r-- 1 dan dan    907 2012-08-22 23:10 win32-ap22py27.mk
-rw-r--r-- 1 dan dan    907 2012-08-22 23:10 win32-ap22py31.mk
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you,

Bill

Comment: you probably should also not be passing `f:/python/python.exe`, as you are not running on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configure script doesn't have execute permissions

You should run `chmod 755 configure` first to give it execute permissions.